# Plot function results for multiple iterations

Tags: r, plot

I've created a function called `evoldeX` that has for output a list of two vectors. With the same entry values, each iteration of this function gives me different results. I am able to plot the result of one iteration.
I'd like to plot 50 iterations of `evoldeX` in one plot to analyze its behavior
I tried this but I know it doesn't work:

```
for(i in 1:50){
    r<-evoldeX(0.4,0.1,10,5,36)
    X=unlist(r[1])
    t=unlist(r[2])
    plot(t ,X,type = "l",lty = 1, col ="red",add=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
r <- evoldeX(0.4,0.1,10,5,36)
X = unlist(r[1])
t = unlist(r[2])
plot(t,X, type = "n", main = "Evoldex") 

clr = rainbow(50)
for(i in 1:50){
    r <- evoldeX(0.4,0.1,10,5,36)
    X = unlist(r[1])
    t = unlist(r[2])
    lines(t,X, type = "l", lty = 1, col =clr[i], add=TRUE)
}
```

you should initialize the plot once, and the you can draw other plots